# Making a windows store control that simulates the message popup (dims the app window)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-interface, windows-store-apps

I want to make a popup control that simulates the message behavior, it dims the original app window (including the app bar and everything else.)

I am a windows 8 newbie but as far as I've searched, there's no control that does that except the message pop up and I cannot use this, I need my own customized view.

Reference the following image for more clarification:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to post example xaml, to show you my idea:

```
<!-- main grid -->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

 <Grid x:Name="Content" VerticalAligment="Stretch" HorizontalAligment="Stretch">
  <!-- Your page content -->
 </Grid>


 <Grid x:Name="Popup" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Gray" Opacity="0.5"  VerticalAligment="Stretch" HorizontalAligment="Stretch">

 <Grid VerticalAligment="Center" HorizontalAligment="Center" Width="300" Height="300">
    <!-- your popup code -->
 </Grid>

</Grid>
```

The idea is to cover the page with semitransparent grid by managing `Popup` grid visibility.

Comment: I had the same idea, but this won't cover the action bar (app bar) when it is on

Comment: You can't cover application bar, however you can close it or try to play with Opacity of the application bar.

Comment: yeah, well. I'll take that as an answer.. this seems to be the best solution so far.